# xdg-open launches both hexchat and firefox

Tags: firefox, xdg-open

I recently noticed that when I click an `irc://` link in my browser (Chromium), it launches HexChat, and when I close HexChat, it will launch Firefox.

Suspicious that it might be something wrong with the Chromium config, I ran `xdg-open irc://` in the terminal, and the same result followed: first HexChat, then Firefox. However...

> $ xdg-settings get default-url-scheme-handler irc
>   io.github.Hexchat.desktop

There is nothing about Firefox. How can I find out why and where Firefox is being summoned?

---

**Edit.** I tried to run this from a terminal, and I think the output can shed some light

> $ xdg-open irc://chat.freenode.net
>   Fatal Python error: PyInterpreterState_Delete: remaining subinterpreters
>
> /usr/bin/xdg-open: line 756:  3718 Aborted                 (core dumped) "$command_exec" "$@"
>   /usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: x-www-browser: command not found
>   Fatal Python error: PyInterpreterState_Delete: remaining subinterpreters

I couldn't find something particularly useful on Google when searching these errors.

(I'm using Arch Linux, if that matters.)

Comment: I originally asked this on SU, but after a few days without any response, I think it might be better received here... I hope.

Comment: I wasn't sure about the tags. I'd be happy to receive some suggestions.

Comment: Two things I would ask 1) What page if any is always opened in firefox, 2) If you do not close HexChat does firefox get launched or only happens after HexChat is closed?

Comment: What's the contents of `io.github.Hexchat.desktop`? It's probably located at `$HOME/.local/share/applications/` or `/usr/share/applications`.

Comment: @George: Firefox only comes up after HexChat is closed. Even if HexChat was already running.

Comment: @Zeta: A bunch of internationalization stuff, and some more. Am I looking for something in particular? Firefox is not mentioned anywhere, of course.

Comment: We're looking for the `Exec` entry. It will probably point to some script. We're looking for the script's contents.

Comment: I have witnessed this same behaviour of `xdg-open` with a different schema and different applications. There is a more general question to be answered here.

Comment: @Zeta: Not really, `Exec=hexchat --existing %U`, and a `whereis hexchat` points to the plain ol' `/usr/bin/hexchat`.

Comment: @JdeBP: Did you also witness a fix for this behavior?